# I want to print my student form to docx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form that can show the result of my student.

This is the program's look:

[image: this is the program's look]

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub PenilaianBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.PenilaianBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MahasiswaDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MahasiswaDataSet.penilaian' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PenilaianTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MahasiswaDataSet.penilaian)
        NimTextBox.Text = ""
        NamaLabel1.Text = ""
        NimLabel1.Text = ""
        TugasLabel1.Text = ""
        UlanganLabel1.Text = ""
        UtsLabel1.Text = ""
        UasLabel1.Text = ""
        HasilLabel1.Text = ""
        SkorLabel1.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnoke_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnoke.Click
        Try
            Dim dt = PenilaianTableAdapter.GetDataBycaridata(NimTextBox.Text)
            If dt.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                NamaLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
                NimLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(2)
                TugasLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(3)
                UlanganLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(4)
                UtsLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(5)
                UasLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(6)
                HasilLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(7)
                SkorLabel1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(8)
            Else
                MsgBox("NIM Yang Anda Input Salah Atau Data Anda Belum Diinput. Silahkan Coba Lagi", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Info")
                NimTextBox.Text = ""
                NamaLabel1.Text = ""
                NimLabel1.Text = ""
                TugasLabel1.Text = ""
                UlanganLabel1.Text = ""
                UtsLabel1.Text = ""
                UasLabel1.Text = ""
                HasilLabel1.Text = ""
                SkorLabel1.Text = ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problems are:

1. I want to print the result of "Oke" button such as; Nama, NIM, Tugas, Ulangan, UTS, UAS, hasil and skor to Microsoft Word template that I've created.

   This is the docx template:
   [image: this is the docx template]
2. I don't know how the code is and how to do that.

Please help me.

Comment: This question is really broad. Have you done any research yourself? What have you tried? What are the problems you ran into?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be some kind of word/excel export. I would suggest you to take a look at this guide as it explains it very well.
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/669509/How-to-Export-Data-to-Excel-in-VB-NET

Comment: thank you, i will do it tomorrow. i will inform you as soon as i try the tips .